# Magento plugins disable/enable problems?

Tags: php, magento, caching, redis, magento-1.9

I am noticing really weird problems after installing plugins.

Sometimes the plugins get disappeared in the backend when we refresh the backend and sometimes it appears in the backend.

I haven''t used magento connect for installing the plugins.

Can this be a caching problems, even though we are using AWS for hosting, we have redis cache.

Also after this whatever plugins we installed also has the configuration in the frontend, So once it has disappeared in the backend, this thing also gets disappeared in the frontend as well.

This problem is really gettting more weird and losing conversion very drastically.

Please someone let me know what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Switch off your Redis and Magento cache then check first.

if this problems does not persist( Try with Magento cache on but redis off ) then you need to check your cache configuration.

Generally it has been observed that on times redis configuration goes wrong resulting in such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Before extension installation is always highly recommended to turn off all cache (magento cache, redis, apc, etc.) and compilation. After installation is recommended to flush magento cache storage.